# Using sailsjs passport Authentication Local strategy is neither giving any error nor authenticating the user

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, sails.js, passport.js

I am trying to implement passport local strategy in my project following this [blog](http://iliketomatoes.com/implement-passport-js-authentication-with-sails-js-0-10-2/). 
I have created the passportjs file in config .

```js
var passport = require('passport'),
  LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    console.log("User Authenticating...." + username + 'and' + password);
    User.findOne({
      username: username
    }).exec(function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, {
          message: 'Unknown user ' + username
        });
      }
      if (user.password != password) {
        return done(null, false, {
          message: 'Invalid password'
        });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

i have updated the httpjs as per suggestion

```js
  middleware: {

    passportInit    : require('passport').initialize(),
    passportSession : require('passport').session(),

     order: [
            'startRequestTimer',
            'cookieParser',
            'session',
            'passportInit',     
            'passportSession', 
            'myRequestLogger',
            'bodyParser',
            'handleBodyParserError',
            'compress',
            'methodOverride',
            'poweredBy',
            'router',
            'www',
            'favicon',
            '404',
            '500'
          ]
     }

  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * The number of seconds to cache flat files on disk being served by        *
  * Express static middleware (by default, these files are in `.tmp/public`) *
  *                                                                          *
  * The HTTP static cache is only active in a 'production' environment,      *
  * since that's the only time Express will cache flat-files.                *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/

  // cache: 31557600000
};
```

Now when I am trying to call local strategy from my Auth controller as

```js
login: function (req, res) {
    var user = req.body.user;

    // check user
    if (!user) {
      //send bad request
      return res.status(500).json({payload : {}, message : "Undefined user"});
    }

    var username = (user.username !== undefined)? user.username : false;
    var password = (user.password != undefined)? user.password : false;

    // Grab user fields.
    if (!username || !password) {
      //send bad request
      return res.status(400).json({payload : {}, message : "Invalid username or password"});
    }
    console.log("before authenticated");
    console.log("username="+username);
    console.log("password="+password);
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
      console.log("User Authenticated");
      if (err) {
        console.log("error=errpr");
        return res.status(400).json({payload : {error: err}, message : info.message});
      }

      if (!user) {
        console.log("error=user");
        return res.status(400).json({payload : {error: err}, message : info.message});
      }
      console.log("User Authenticated2");
      _authTokenRequestCb(user,req,res);

    })(req,res);
  },
```

It never authenticate the user and the console log statement in Paasportjs.

> > console.log("User Authenticating...."+username+'and'+password);

also never executed.I am not getting any error also .
Can anybody suggest where I am getting it wrong.

Update:I have found in this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278098/express-js-passport-authentication-automatically-fails-skips-strategy?rq=1) "If 'email' or 'password' are not provided passport just automatically fails. I guess some documentation of that would have been useful!."
But as console log statement giving me the username and passwoprd (in the registerblock

```
console.log("before authenticated");
console.log("username="+username);
console.log("password="+password);
```

So I am sure this is not the case.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a policy file to say which controller actions are to be authenticated? Passport doesn't have a policy to deny access to a controller. For this, you have to create another policy.

Just have a look at this answer: [Passport authentication not working in Sails JS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27168229/passport-authentication-not-working-in-sails-js-application)

Let me know if this doesn't help.

Comment: I have mobile client(built on angular js) which send a request as $http.post(Constants.API.baseUrl+'/login', {user: userData}).success(success).error(error);

Comment: I think it's better to use API authentication instead of username and password. Please have a look at this: [even-more-passport](https://github.com/sails101/even-more-passport)

Comment: This request will Authenticate the user and create a fresh token every time and every request we are checking for that token whether it is equel to stored token or not.The login action have no need to be authenticated.It will authenticate the user. My problem is when I am calling the "  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {" it not caaling the local strategy ,(to check it i have made a console.log statement in local startegy ,but it never fired.)"